# using sed/awk on bash script variables

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to get the name of a DNS server `4.2.2.1`.

Using `host 4.2.2.1` I get this output:

```
1.2.2.4.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer a.resolvers.level3.net
```

in my script, I do this as:

```
name="$($host $server)"
```

How can I use sed/awk on `$name` to only get the `a.resolvers.level3.net`, keeping in mind that I'll use this on completely different servers so I can't just `grep a.resolvers` out of the variable?

Comment: I assume the `name="$($host $server)"` is a typoand you're actually using `name="$(host $server)"`, right? Also, I removed a trailing `.` from your `host` output since that looked like a typo. Please confirm that it was indeed not supposed to be there.

Comment: @terdon DNS allows a trailing dot in names, and indeed `host` outputs them.

Comment: @jlmg ah, thanks, I didn't know that.

Comment: First result in Google search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426659/how-extract-last-part-of-string-in-bash

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to slice the string :

```
echo ${name##* }
```

This will slice the string and keep the part starting from the last space to the end.

```
${name <-- from name  
  ##   <-- trim the front  
  *    <-- matches anything  
  ' '  <-- until the last ' '  
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do would be to use `awk` and tell it to print the last field:

```
$ echo "$name" | awk '{print $NF}'
a.resolvers.level3.net
```

Of course, if all you need is the server's IP, you may as well get that into `name` in the first place so you don't need to process it later:

```
name=$(host $server | awk '{print $NF}')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
name=$(host "$server" | grep -o '[^[:space:]]*$')
```

will select the trailing portion of  the host command's output.

Answer (score 3):

Just putting a `sed` alternative as well. This will print last column from a string separated by whitespaces.

```
 sed 's/.*[[:space:]]\(.*\)$/\1/'
```

I tested it for cases where `a.resolvers.level3.net` is the only string in the $name variable and it works.

```
$ echo "$name"
1.2.2.4.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer a.resolvers.level3.net
$
$ echo "$name"|sed 's/.*[[:space:]]\(.*\)$/\1/'
a.resolvers.level3.net
$
$ name="a.resolvers.level3.net"
$ echo "$name"|sed 's/.*[[:space:]]\(.*\)$/\1/'
a.resolvers.level3.net
$
```

Answer (score 3):

A far shorter answer, involving no string manipulation at all, is

```
dig +short -x 4.2.2.1
```

which displays

```
a.resolvers.level3.net.
```

and nothing more. Of course you have to have dig installed.